# winegstreamer broken with >=glib-2.32.0, how to check the glib version in ubuntu?

Tags: wine, games, glib

I am a novice to Ubuntu and don't know which keyword should be put in Google.
I wine a game but the game couldn't play a video.

Someone tell me that you may come across the bug in wine,
but I'm not sure if I have the same bug in my ubuntu12.04.

I have the wine1.6 installed.

Here is the wine bug link: http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30557

I will appreciate it if anyone tell me how to check the glib version.

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg -s libglib2.0-0 |grep Version` should do the trick.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Oh,my god. It works. Great thanks. The terminal output is "Version: 2.32.3-0ubuntu1". It's really a bug.

Comment: On multiarch (such as Debian testing to be Jessie) it's better to use `libglib2.0-bin` for detection (as current package contains arch, e.g. `libglib2.0-0:amd64`).